# I add tabIndex for a div element and add onblur attribute for it. It works well on my laptop but it didn't work on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a element in my html as follows.

```
<div tabindex="-1" onblur="javascript:alert('hellow');">KKKKK</div>
```

the blur event is fired correctly on my laptop but it can't be fired on mobile(just in IOS device).

anyone know that's why? thanks in advance.

Comment: which browser on mobile

Comment: Any browser, for example UC, safari and so on. I test this on many browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the reason. The elements(such as div form and span) are not clickable in IOS device. so the div can't get focus.

so I fix this problem like this.

```
<div width="400px" height="400px" onclick="javascript: function(e){e.preventDefault();}">
   <div width="200px" height="200px" onclick="javascript: function(e){e.preventDefault();}" onblur="javascript: console.log('blur....')"> inner div</div>
  outer div
</div>
```

but When I click the `out div` all the screen will be flush.

so I need to fix it. anyone have some advice to me for this.